# Вставка записей в базу данных MySQL в цикле

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Необходимо вставить записи в таблицу в цикле. Логика такая что в поле `OrderID` вставляется один и тот же идентификатор заказа, а в поле `ProductID` идентификаторы всех товаров добавленных в заказ.
Пытаюсь так:

```
$ids=array_keys($productsInCart);
   for ($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++){
       $query ="INSERT INTO tblOrderProduct (OrderID,ProductID)
                VALUES('$orderid','$ids')";
       $mysqli->query($query);
   }
```

Массив `$productsInCart` содержит идентификаторы товаров и их кол-во соответственно. В общем не получается реализовать, подскажите что не так.

Comment: Наверное надо было использовать $ids[$i] в запросе или что то в этом роде ...

Comment: @Mike действительно проглядел! спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С вашего позволения, я бы предложил вам воспользоваться многострочным оператором `INSERT`, таким образом вы сможете вставить записи одним вызовом, а не множеством в цикле

```
<?php
$ids = array_keys($productsInCart);
$sql = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
  $sql[] = "('$orderid', '{$ids[$i]}')";
}
if(count($sql) > 0) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO tblOrderProduct (OrderID, ProductID)
            VALUES " . implode(",", $sql);
  $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

Comment: Скобочки проверьте, по виду у вас закрывающих больше чем открывающих. Синтаксис должен быть  `insert into tab (f1,f2) values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3)`

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: спасибо, пригодилось!